# How to query a small dataset using Python

Tags: python, dataset

I need help with identifying subsets of data from a csv file using Python. I have a dataset containing an inventory of fruit along with a Type field as below.

```
Item    Type   
Apple   10         
Orange  5          
Pear    8          
Apple   10  
Pear    5
Orange  2
Pear    5
```

I need to be able to identify/split this dataset into subsets of fruit and type.

Expected output is another field with a number to indicate the category it should go into:

```
 Item    Type   Category
 Apple   10     1
 Orange  5      2   
 Pear    8      3   
 Apple   10     1
 Pear    5      4
 Orange  5      2
 Pear    5      4
```

I'm new to Python so need help with the actual logic

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you please show the expected output

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that second last line of expected answer should remain as "Orange 2" for Item and type:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([['Apple', '10'], 
                       ['Orange', '5'], 
                       ['Pear', '8'], 
                       ['Apple', '10'], 
                       ['Pear', '5'], 
                       ['Orange', '2'], 
                       ['Pear', '5']], 
                      columns = ['Item', 'Type'])

categories = []
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if tuple(row) not in categories:
        categories.append(tuple(row))
df["Category"] = [categories.index(tuple(row))+1 for index,row in df.iterrows()]
print(df)
```

This will give

```
     Item Type  Category
0   Apple   10         1
1  Orange    5         2
2    Pear    8         3
3   Apple   10         1
4    Pear    5         4
5  Orange    2         5
6    Pear    5         4
```

Since there's no special pandas operation here, using pandas isn't that necessary (though it may be useful for other operations). The key is to define a unique list of tuples that records each combination of Item and Type and use the index function to find it again.

Comment: Answer was posted before OP's edit of expected output. Not sure if expected output is actually correct now - Orange 2 has changed to Orange 5. OP should now clarify.

Comment: Thanks! the assumption is fine. But would the solution differ if we weren't using pandas?

Comment: No, since the list of items in the Category column was constructed without any help from pandas. So you could just read the file with the usual open() function and split the lines, and use "for line in lines" instead of "for index,row in ...".

Comment: generally it’s a bad idea to iterate over rows of a dataframe, in fact it should always be an absolute last resort

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand your question.

If you want to read csv file, you can use `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
```

You can also use the `sep` parameter for use custom separator.

Comment: if you don't understand the question, please do not post an answer

Comment: I am trying to help as I understand it, waiting for the author's clarifications.

Comment: he clarified and this is not what he wants